# Is having sex with wife for non-reporduction purpose sin?

Tags: marriage, sin, sex, kama, wife

Should sex be done only for the reproduction purpose ?
Is having sex with one's wife for the purpose of enjoyment wrong ? Is it sin ?

Comment: Sexual intercourse is reproduction. As for pregnancy, that is something which would happen as a result, usually (unless there's some complication). This is because emission of vīrya in a place other than the yoni of woman (in maithuna) such as mouth, etc., is pāpa, as per dharmaśāstras.
As for enjoyment, that is an added perk to the intercourse.